# Different version of MFCO42D.dll causing Debug error - VC++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll

I am developing a program using visual studio c++ 6.0 with following code

> Log("User Click OK.");
>                   BatchPiLot *batchPilot = new BatchPiLot(this);
>                   Log("Start Do Modal.");
>                   batchPilot->DoModal();

When I run the program with MFCO42D.dll version 6.0.8168 located in same folder with the EXE, It run smoothly without any error.

When I try to deploy to another computer with MFCO42D.dll version 6.0.8665 located in same folder with the EXE, It gives debug error, the value of ESP was not properly saved across function..bla..bla..bla.when calling

> BatchPiLot *batchPilot = new BatchPiLot(this);

When I replace the dll to older version...It run smoothly again.

How To solve this problem?
I want to run the program with the newest MFCO42D.dll.
Is my calling function got problem?

Comment: `When I try to deploy to another computer` Stop what you're doing.  You are not supposed to deploy debug versions of the runtime library on other computers.  Doing so violates the Microsoft license agreement.

Comment: Hi PaulMcKenzie,thanks for response.What I meant is copy the program to another computer and run its. Is it what you mean?Am I need to set active configuration to release?

Comment: Yes.  You can only deploy release versions of your application.

Comment: Microsoft has a list of components that are considered "distributable" to the general public in their Visual C++ compiler suite.  These distributables include release versions of the runtime libraries.  Debug libraries are for development purposes only and cannot be legally installed or copied on machines that do not have a licensed version of Visual C++ installed.

Comment: Thanks PaulMcKenzie for sharing this info....I just know about this.

Comment: msvc6? welcome to 1998?